# Globals with Browserify / ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browserify

I have several `ReactJS` components that access some globals, it works fine if it's in one file, but if I seperate them and export them with `module.exports`, bundle it with `browserify` it doesn't work anymore. At the moment all the ''globals'' are in the `index.js` where also the React Rendering takes place.

I know that globals are a bad thing and I'm working on that, but in the meantime I want to modularize the coding. I found some solutions on the internet, BUT nothing that is somehow easy (for **much** globals).

So the questions are, what's the best (easiest, with the least work) way for a temporary solution and how to get rid of globals on the long-term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Fast

You can assign properties to `window`, which is a global context in the browser, or `global`, which is the global context in node. e.g., `window.myGlobal = 5`.

#### Intuitive

If your globals are static, you can create a module containing global values, and `require` it wherever needed. [Module references are cached](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_caching), meaning that repeated `require` loads return a reference to the same object; while you could exploit this fact to manage variable globals, this approach feels brittle to me.

#### My Preference

You can assign a function to `module.exports`; something like:

```
// myModule.js
module.exports = function(kindaGlobal){ 
    ...do something with kindaGlobal...
    return {
       ...some object with properties referencing kindaGlobal...
    };
};
```

Then you can pass your "global" value from `index.js`:

```
var myModule = require('./myModule.js')(myGlobal);
```

If `myGlobal` is not a primitive (e.g., a string, number, etc.) it is "passed-by-reference", so it can be modified within the module in a way accessible to other modules.

#### React-y

React encourages you to pass data as component properties from the top down, while children pass data from the bottom up using callbacks. A common pattern is the use of [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html#content) or [Redux](http://redux.js.org/) to manage a "global" datastore that high-level components subscribe to, while low-level components alter the store using "actions".

cf. [React Docs: "Communicate Between Components"](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html)

cf. [React Docs: "Expose Component Functions"](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/expose-component-functions.html)